# How to encode gob in UTF-8 in golang ?

Tags: go, utf-8, encode

I am using **gob.NewEncoder** to encode string message *msg* but need to do it in utf-8.

err= gob.NewEncoder(conn).Encode(msg)

I am getting warning in Ruby receiver (Logstash) saying that *Received an event that has a different character encoding than you configured ...:expected_charset=>"UTF-8"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `Encode(msg)`, you are not sending UTF-8 plain text.

To send plain text:

```
conn.Write([]byte(msg)) // suppose msg is string
```